# How do I print IPC message between a and b on linux in C?

Tags: c, linux, ipc

Suppose I'm root,so privilege is not an issue.

How can I print IPC message between arbitrary two local processes ?

Comment: Looks like an interesting question, but you should add more details about what you want.

Comment: IPC is a high level terminology not a particular technology so the question requires further thought.

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile way is to use sockets.  If your message is an integral type then signals will work too.

Depends on what the message looks like.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, it would be helpful if you posted more detail as to what you want to do. I did find these links that might help get you started: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/sharedmemipc.aspx